# Python Plotly Dash: how the set layout for a vertical screen?

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to adjust the layout for the vertical screen.
To do this I use the parameter `transform: rotate (270deg)` in the layout style.
The problem is that I can not even fit graphs to a vertical layout.
Example:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/5d1ea79569ed194d432e56108a04d188/raw/a9f9e8076b837d541398e999dcbac2b2826a81f8/gdp-life-exp-2007.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdp per capita", y="life expectancy",
                 size="population", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                 log_x=True, size_max=60)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig_2 = px.bar(df_2, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    ),
        dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig_2
    )
], 
    style={
          'margin-top': '50px',
          'margin-bottom': '50px',
          'margin-left': '50px',
          'margin-right': '50px',
          'transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
          'backgroundColor':'gray',
          }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Horizontal mode:
[image]

Vertical mode:
[image]

So as you can see in vertical mode graphs do not fit themselves and a lot of empty space is left in the layout.
Changes in parameters like `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` within style do not change anything.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS property `width` will control your graph's height (since you are flipping the Div, width and height switch meanings in this context). For example, you could apply n% of a page's height to that of the div's (e.g. `width: 70%;`), so this value will depend on what you want to show and how big you want the graphs. You could also give it an explicit pixel value (e.g. `width: 400px`). So something like this could work:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/5d1ea79569ed194d432e56108a04d188/raw/a9f9e8076b837d541398e999dcbac2b2826a81f8/gdp-life-exp-2007.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdp per capita", y="life expectancy",
                 size="population", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                 log_x=True)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig_2 = px.bar(df_2, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    ),
        dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig_2
    )
], 
    style={
          'margin-top': '50px',
          'margin-bottom': '50px',
          'margin-left': '50px',
          'margin-right': '50px',
          'backgroundColor':'gray',
          'width': '50%',
          'transform': 'rotate(270deg)'
          }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```